# Boot failed after building a new kernel. (kernel options hide)

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, kernel

I built a new kernel and reboot my notebook with the new kernel.
Unfortunately, the boot failed.

I want to reboot by using the original kernel, but there is a windows boot manager which hide the kernel choosing menu.

There are only two choices in the boot manager:

1.Windows 7

2.Ubuntu

The Ubuntu option can not be chosen in more detailed. I think the Ubuntu option is set to use the latest kernel I built.

What can I do now? :"(

---

Update: 
Now I can see my /home by Ubuntu install CD. Using "try Ubuntu" option.
Any thing I can do to recovery my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grub appear by modifying the /etc/default/grub as the following!

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then I can choose which kernel I want to use to boot.